# How to move xaml code inside HierarchicalDataTemplate to a resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have the following `TreeView` with several `HierarchicalDataTemplates`. Inside every HierarchicalDataTemplate I have a block of xaml code to define the structure of my object X.

**TreeView Example**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           FontSize="15" 
                           FontWeight="Medium"
                           Foreground="Brown"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Now I would like to move the StackPanel to a resource, e.x. inside UserControl resource.
I tried defining a `DataTemplate` and using it as `ItemTemplate` for the HierarchicalDataTemplate but this does not work.

**My attempt:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ModuleTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type local:Module}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   FontSize="15" 
                   FontWeight="Medium"
                   Foreground="Brown"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- TreeView section-->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModuleTemplate}">
```

The idea from @mm8 is fine and would work, but in my case that would lead to many `UserControls`. I Would rather prefer something simpler.

Any ideas how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Why are you not using the `{StaticResource}` markup? What makes you think you could use the name of the resource key, `"ModuleTemplate"`, as the _path_ for a binding expression? I would expect `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModuleTemplate}"` to work just fine.

Comment: Note that the `ItemTemplate` will be applied to the children (modules) and not the the cars themselves. The question seems to be about how to move the "xaml code *inside* (the) HierarchicalDataTemplate to a resource".

Comment: @PeterDuniho It was only a typo.. Of course I use `{StaticResource}` markup. **mm8** perfectly summarized my intention. I saw your proposal to use `UserControl` but this is not exactly what I am searching for. Has someone else an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still just want to move the code inside (the) HierarchicalDataTemplate to UserControl.Resources ...

Then define the `StackPanel` as non-shared resource using the [x:Shared attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Key="sp" x:Shared="False">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   FontSize="15" 
                   FontWeight="Medium"
                   Foreground="Brown"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource sp}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: There we go! That's the solution I searched from the start. To summarize, I didn't know that I could define a `StackPanel` with an **x:Key** and **x:Shared** propertys and then use it as a resource in a `ContentControl`. Was my question so bad to understand that people voted it down? Anyway thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score -1):

> Now I would like to move the StackPanel to a resource, e.x. inside UserControl resource.

Try this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <local:UserControl1 />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

...where `UserControl1` is a `UserControl` with the `StackPanel` in it:

```
<UserControl...>
    <StackPanel>...</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It would work, but like I mentioned above I don't want to have that many `UserControls`. Maybe someone else finds an other solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking then.Why would you end up with "that many" UserControls?

Comment: I know it sounds a bit confusing, but I would like to keep the resources **Inside the User Control** where I have my `TreeView` but just move it outside the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` declaration. Your solution will generate new classes (User Controls) and that's what I don't want.

Comment: @Stan1k: Can you give an example of such a resource?

Comment: Of course. For example the `DataTemplate` "ModuleTemplate" which you can see under my question. This one I would like to put for example under `UserControl.Resources` where User Control is the same one, where my TreeView is. Shortly, I would like to have this all in one class, but the `TreeView` control be as small as possible.

Comment: So why don't you put the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in `UserControl.Resources`?

Comment: Because I still just want to move the code **inside (the) HierarchicalDataTemplate** to `UserControl.Resources`, not the entire `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. But it looks like this is not possible.. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean that you want to move the `StackPanel`?